# Where can I find Microsoft Test Controller 2012 installer

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I tried to find it in both TFS and Visual Studio (Premium) installation media.
Also tried to find a donwload from MS website, but can't find it there.

Where can I find it? (as well as Test Agent installers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Test Agents for Test Manager is a feature included in the Premium and Ultimate editions available for the MSDN Subscribers:

### [Agents for Visual Studio 2012 (x86) - DVD (English)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/downloads/hh442898.aspx#FileId=49775)

[image: Agents for Visual Studio 2012 (x86) - DVD (English)]

Answer (score 1):

I found this link [Visual Studio Agents 2010 - ISO](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1334)

I'm going to edit this answer if i find something more interesting for you.

But do I have to look on that way?

Comment: This, there are two installers, the TFS installer doesn't contain the agents, so you'll need to download the above one as well.